# OpenCV stereosgbm code - unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, opencv, unresolved-external

This is an extract from openCV 2.4 *stereosgbm.cpp , calcPixelCostBT()* function.
After I have migrated the project from Visual Studio 2012 to 2019, I get unresolved external symbol error.

I have narrowed down the cause of error to be in these lines

```
const PixType*row1 = img1.ptr<PixType>(y);
const PixType*row2 = img2.ptr<PixType>(y);
```

`PixType` is `unsigned char`

`img1` , `img2` are `class sgbm::Image`

[Error message snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hPhy.jpg)

Any understanding on what's happening here would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The exact error message you recieve would be a help.

Comment: Unresolved symbols are linker problems so maybe you can show how the linker is called. That is very likely a missing library

Comment: @john I have added the error message screenshot

Comment: Strange as that function should be defined inline in the mat.hpp header file. So an unresolved external seems to be impossible. But another strange thing is the the version 2.4 stereosgbm.cpp file I looked at doesn't contain the lines you quoted (at least not exactly as you quoted them). So something weird going on, but I have no idea what.